# How can I alter the Request.RawUrl property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC's BeginForm helper uses the Request.RawUrl property when crafting a form's action.  I'm sure this is generally fine but it is causing an issue for me.

I use a URL rewriter on my site.  In the global.asax I have the following code to straighten out the rewriter's actions.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var app = sender as HttpApplication;
  if (app != null)
    if (app.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Contains("~/rewritten.mvc"))
      app.Context.RewritePath(app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("/rewritten.mvc", ""));
}
```

The problem is that the app.RewritePath does not affect the RawUrl property so when the BeginForm helper writes the action it ends up with the "/rewritten.mvc" embedded in the target url which is incorrect.

I know I can use an overload in the BeginForm() method to specifically target a controller and action but this has its own drawbacks, and in my particular case I cannot do that.

In my Application_BeginRequest method, what can do to alter the output of the RawUrl property?  (I guess I should mention that this property doesn't have a setter.)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Piedone, sorry, I don't recall what we eventually did.  This was at an old job and I know longer have access to the source code to see what the final solution was.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Unfortunately I now have the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327413/asp-net-mvc-app-routes-breaking-when-rewritten-through-iis-url-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the RawUrl property.  Have you looked at using the routing functionality built into MVC instead of using an external re-writer?